# Word 2007: Is it possible to have paragraph justification in a style?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

When I create a style for paragraphs, I can only change the alignment. Is there anyway to add justification to a paragraph style and not do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can.**

I have 2010, so I can't give you screen shots, but it can be done when you modify or create a style. Below are instructions how to do that.

[Style basics in Word - Customized styles](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/style-basics-in-word-HA010230882.aspx#BM4)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't check the alignment drop down menu. It has justification. Also, thanks for linking the useful article.